# Using CGRectIntersectsRect to detect a collision between two CAlayers

Tags: objective-c, calayer, collision

I am trying to use CGRectIntersectsRect to detect a collision between two CAlayers. One is part of a hierarchy of layers, and the other is a sublayer of the main view. I have tried this:

[Accessing presentationLayer of an animation to detect collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655264/accessing-presentationlayer-of-an-animation-to-detect-collisions/13655289#13655289)

It does not work with any consistency. Here is what I have right now. "LegLowerLeft" is part of a hierarchy of CAlayers and "rec2" is a subview of the main view. Thanks in advance for any help.:

```
-(void) checkForCollisionWithRec{
  if(CGRectIntersectsRect(((CALayer*)self.creature.legLowerLeft.presentationLayer).frame,
                            ((CALayer*)rec2.presentationLayer).frame))

    { NSLog(@"Collision detected"); }

   else{NSLog(@"No collision detected");}
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The frame of a layer is in the coordinate space of its superview. If two layers have different superviews, then you cannot compare their frames directly. You must convert them to a consistent coordinate space.

```
CALayer *layer1 = self.creature.legLowerLeft.presentationLayer;
CALayer *layer2 = rec2.presentationLayer;

CGRect frame1 = layer1.frame;
CGRect frame2 = [layer1 convertRect:layer2.frame fromLayer:layer2];

if(CGRectIntersectsRect(frame1, frame2))
{
  NSLog(@"Collision detected");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"No collision detected");
}
```

Comment: Strange. This works great for every CALayer in my project but to one I need it to work for. It works when I am comparing parts of the creature class hierarchy to each other (a character I made out of CALayers), but not outside it. Anyway I think I came up with another solution to do what I need to do. Thanks this should still be useful  for other things.