# Using NSTimer to continuously shift UIViews upwards looks jumpy/not smooth

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, nstimer

I am making an iphone game using Xcode 6 Beta 5, with Swift. It currently looks like this :[image]

The user has to use their finger to maneuver between the blocks, which are moving upwards. To do this, I have created UIViews for each of the blocks, and used an algorithm to generate a random path. I first used animateWithDuration to move the blocks upward, but complications arose when I tried to add in the detection for when a user touches the blocks.

I am now trying to do the animation using an NSTimer:

```
var shiftBlockTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("shiftBlocks"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func shiftBlocks() {
    for leftBlock in leftBlocks {
         leftBlock.frame.origin.y -= 70
    }

    for rightBlock in rightBlocks {
         rightBlock.frame.origin.y -= 70
    }
}
```

This does work, however the movement is all jumpy and not the smooth movement I was hoping for, and had when I was using animateWithDuration.

Is there any way I can get this movement to become smoother, without increasing the number of iterations? (This slows down my app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `NSTimer` for animation.  Use `CADisplayLink`.  [From the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html):

> A `CADisplayLink` object is a timer object that allows your application to synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display.

Realistically, though, don't use `CADisplayLink` either.  Use SpriteKit.  It's designed for 2D games like this.

Comment: You beat me to it. Definitely try this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Core Animation to animate the layer (`view.layer`).

> complications arose when I tried to add in the detection for when a user touches the blocks.

You can avoid these complications by detecting collisions with the view's *presentation layer* (`view.layer.presentationLayer`). See [Accessing presentationLayer of an animation to detect collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13655264/1445366).

---

More info from Apple's [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html):

> Objects in the **presentation tree** contain the in-flight values for any running animations. Whereas the layer tree objects contain the target values for an animation, the objects in the presentation tree reflect the current values as they appear onscreen. You should never modify the objects in this tree. Instead, you use these objects to read current animation values, perhaps to create a new animation starting at those values.

Comment: Let me put it another way. Never never never never use NSTimer to do animation. :)